# waypoint : removeClass is not defined

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$('.something').waypoint(function(direction) {
  if(direction === "down") {
    $("nav").fadeOut(function(){
        removeClass("sticky_nav");
    });
  }else if(direction === "up") {
      $("nav").fadeIn(function(){
        addClass("sticky_nav");
      });
  }
}, { offset: 100 });
```

when I scroll until the target the console say `removeClass is not defined`, why?
but the `fadeOut` did appear..

Comment: Because you have written `removeClass()` instead of `$(this).removeClass()`?

Answer (score 0):

You need to perform addclass on some object, like `$(this).removeClass()`

Answer (score 0):

You should use the remove class on some html element only..
For example:

```
$('P').removeClass()
```

This will remove the class(which it has already) in all paragraph elements

For more information Refer : [removeClass](http://api.jquery.com/removeClass/)